# R - remove double quotes from arguements

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to get rows corresponding to maximum value of a particular variable. I am very new in R and this method was given on a website, I am just trying to create a function out of the method given on the site.

Please see the code below.

```
uniMax2 <- function(mydf,myid,maxOf) {
# mydf - data.frame, myid - sorting variable
# maxOf - variable to be used for maximum value

  mydf.s = mydf[order(mydf[[myid]],mydf[[maxOf]]),]
  myid.uni <- unique(mydf.s[[myid]])
  ln <- length(myid.uni)
  last <- c()

  for(i in 1:ln) {
    temp <-subset(mydf.s,myid==myid.uni[i])
    if (dim(temp)[1]>1) {
      last.temp <- temp[dim(temp)[1],]
    }
    else {
      last.temp <- temp
    }
    last = rbind(last, last.temp)
  }
  return(last)
}
```

when I use this function like this 
     uniMax2(hsb2,"prog","math")

Problem is in this line

```
temp <-subset(mydf.s,myid==myid.uni[i])
```

I think this line is resolved as

```
temp <-subset(mydf.s,"prog"==myid.uni[i])
```

However it should get resolved as

```
temp <-subset(mydf.s,prog==myid.uni[i])
```

Kindly help.

Comment: There should be an easier way to do that. This line: `mydf[mydf$maxOf==max(mydf$maxOf),]` returns the row that contains the max of the variable `maxOf`.

Comment: But if you want to use your function, `eval(parse(text = myid))==....` could work.

Comment: Thansk GPierre, Though I came across the easier solution that you mentioned, I still wanted to know how to come around with this quote problem. Thanks for your reply, it worked well.

Comment: Ok I will post the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way to return the row that contains the max of the variable `maxOf`:

```
mydf[mydf$maxOf==max(mydf$maxOf),]
```

To make the function work:

```
temp <-subset(mydf.s,eval(parse(text = myid))==myid.uni[i])
```

Comment: you maybe can also use `which.max` as a shortcut, `which.max(mydf$maxOf)`